# Show that the equation $ \cos(x) - kx = 0$ has a unique solution in $[0, \pi/2]$ for all $k>0$

Tags: trigonometry, roots

Show that the equation $$f(x;k) \equiv \cos(x) - kx = 0$$ has a unique solution in $[0, \pi/2]$ for all $k>0$.

Answer (score 3):

The function $g(x)=\cos x-kx$ is the sum of two strictly decreasing functions in $[0,\pi/2]$, so it can not have more than one zero.

On the other hand, $g(0)=1>0$ and $g(\pi/2)=-k\pi/2<0$. By Bolzano's theorem, it must have one zero.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$f(x) = \cos(x) - kx $
with $k > 0$.

$f(0) = 1$
and
$f(\pi/2)
=-k\pi/2
< 0
$,
so
$f$ has at least one root there.

$f'(x)
=-\sin(x)-k
< 0
$
so $f$ is decreasing,
so it can have at most one root.

Therefore $f$
has exactly one root.

Note that the same proof
shows the same thing
for
$f(x)
=a\cos(x)-kx
$
with both
$a$ and $k$ positive.